# Create geometry column of type 'PointZM' in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I want to add a geometry column with geometry like "PointZM", "PolygonZM". I have written something like this:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('data_rivne','geo_point','geom2',0,'POINTZM',0);
```

But it doesn't work. It says:

> Invalid type name "POINTZM(0)"

Can I create a column with such geometry, and what dimensions must I use?

Comment: I advise you to check the synopsis following this [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/AddGeometryColumn.html)

Comment: I have read this documentetion, but there nothing about ZM.

Comment: I think that the documentation is not very clear. Perhaps worth writing a documentation feature request into PostGIS-users list. However, pointZM with zero dimensions does not make sense at all. Create a point with 4 dimensions instead. This is quite nice reading https://www.e-education.psu.edu/spatialdb/node/1960.

Comment: Confirmed that it can be puzzling. It is like `AddGeometryColumn('test','newgeom',0,'POINT',4)` but same kind of column can be created with `ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN newgeom geometry(PointZM)`. A clear example in AddGeometryColumn would be good to have.

Comment: AddGeometryColumn('test','newgeom',0,'POINT',4) It worked, thanks!